# Отношения многие ко многим, как добавлять существующие значения в таблицу, если они уникальны?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

Вообщем у меня есть код, который добавляет Теги из ArticleController - в таблицу Tag значения(поле алиас уникальное), и сохраняется в промежуточную таблицу (т.к. есть связь многие ко многим )
Как сделать так, чтобы если есть уже такой тег с уникальным ключем alias - он пропускал его(или просто обновлял) и не было ошибки, что поле уникально и нельзя добавить в БД

```
    public function addArticle($request){
     $data = $request->except('_token');

     /* Блок для тегов*/

     if ($data['tags_title']){
         $data['tags_alias'] = $this->transliterate($data['tags_title']);
     }

     $tags = explode(',', $data['tags_title']);
     $tags_alias = array();
     foreach ($tags as $tag_alias){
         $tag_alias  = $this->transliterate($tag_alias);
         /*dump($tag_alias);*/
         array_push($tags_alias, $tag_alias);
     }
     $tags_merge = array_combine($tags, $tags_alias);
     /*dd($data, $tags, $tags_alias, $tags_merge);*/

    /*Блок для тегов закончен */


    if (empty($data['alias'])){ //если пустая ячейка в массиве data
        $data['alias'] = $this->transliterate($data['title']);
    }

    if ($this->one($data['alias'],false)){
        $request->merge(array('alias' => $data['alias']));
        $request->flash();

        return ['error' => 'Данный псевдоним уже используется'];
    }

    if($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $image = $request->file('img');

        if ($image->isValid()) {
            $str = str_random(8);

            $obj = new \stdClass();
            $obj->mini = $str.'_mini.jpg';
            $obj->max = $str.'_max.jpg';
            $obj->path = $str.'.jpg';

            $img = Image::make($image);

            $img->fit(Config::get('settings.articles_img_full')['width'],
                      Config::get('settings.articles_img_full')['height'])->
                      save(public_path().'/'.env('THEME').'/images/articles/'.$obj->path);

            $img->fit(Config::get('settings.articles_img')['max']['width'],
                Config::get('settings.articles_img')['max']['height'])->
            save(public_path().'/'.env('THEME').'/images/articles/'.$obj->max);

            $img->fit(Config::get('settings.articles_img')['mini']['width'],
                Config::get('settings.articles_img')['mini']['height'])->
            save(public_path().'/'.env('THEME').'/images/articles/'.$obj->mini);

            $data['img'] = json_encode($obj);

            $this->model->fill($data);

            if ($request->user()->articles()->save($this->model)) {
                    foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){

                            $this->model->tags()->create([
                                'title' => $key,
                                'alias' => $value
                            ]);



                    }

                    return ['session' => 'Материал добавлен'];
            }
        }
    }



}
```

вот такой код делает проверку и значение else - добавляет в базу, если поле Алиас новое

```
if ($request->user()->articles()->save($this->model)) {
                foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){
                    if (array_search($value, Tag::all()->pluck('alias')->toArray())){
                        continue;
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->model->tags()->create([
                            'title' => $key,
                            'alias' => $value
                        ]);
                    }


                }

                    return ['session' => 'Материал добавлен'];
            }
```

что мне нужно подставить на место continue - чтобы просто привязало запись из существующей БД ?

Comment: Пробуйте `firstOrNew()` или `firstOrCreate()`. [Other Creation Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но не работает. Либо пропускает теги - firstOrNew, либо снова ошибка дубликата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Найдем существующий или создадим новый тег при помощи метода `firstOrCreate()`.

2) Приатачим тег к текущей модели при помощи метода `attach()` отношения `belongsToMany`

```
if ($request->user()->articles()->save($this->model)) {
    foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
            'title' => $key,
            'alias' => $value
        ]);
        $this->model->tags()->attach($tag->id);
    }

    return ['session' => 'Материал добавлен'];
}
```

Для обновления (будет работать и в создании) можно использовать метод `sync()` отношения `belongsToMany`:

```
if ($request->user()->articles()->save($this->model)) {

    $tags = [];

    foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
            'title' => $key,
            'alias' => $value
        ]);
        $tags[] = $tag->id;
    }

    $this->model->tags()->sync($tags);

    return ['session' => 'Материал добавлен'];
}
```

`sync()` сам сделает нужные `attach()` и `detach()` на основе массива, который в него передадите.

Comment: Спасибо большое! всё работает, но немного подправил код - 
if ($request->user()->articles()->save($this->model)) {
                    foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){
                        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['title' => $key, 'alias' => $value,]);
                        $this->model->tags()->attach($tag->id);
                    }

                    return ['session' => 'Материал добавлен'];
                }

Только очень странно, что моя IDE - PHP storm подсвечивает, что для Tag:: - метода firstOrCreate - не существует...очень странно

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов Это магический метод. То есть статического метода firstOrCreate физически не существует, но есть не статический firstOrCreate. Модель это понимает и вызывает этот метод, когда вы к нему обращаетесь статически. Чтобы шторм нормально резолвил магические методы, надо поставить пакет laravel-ide-helper (можно найти на github) и запустить 3 команды из документации.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь и за совет! Постараюсь установить этот пакет!

Comment: Добрый день! Можете помочь ещё раз пожалуйста)  - как этот код изменить - чтобы правильно работал метод - update для записи?

А то сейчас работает так - если новые добавляю - работает, а если удаляю, то ничего не меняется...

if ($article->update()) {
            foreach ($tags_merge as $key => $value){
                $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['title' => $key, 'alias' => $value,]);
                $article->tags()->attach($tag->id);
            }
            return ['session' => 'Материал обновлен'];
        }

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов добавил в конце ответа.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё получилось, также немного если по другому сделать - тоже работает. Перед циклом просто все теги отдетачить))

$article->tags()->detach();

И он заново проверяет и добавляет! Спасибо вам огромное за оперативность и вариативность кода!